# Use MAC Address to Identify Laptop Model?

Tags: hardware, mac-address

Is it possible to use the first 6 characters (D8:9D:67) of a MAC address to learn the model/version of the device? For example, [this MAC address belong to Hewlett Packard](https://macaddress.webwat.ch/hwaddr/D8:9D:67). But they manufacture printers, laptops, desktops, tablets, etc... Are there any public databases to help give *some idea* what kind of device the MAC address belongs to?

Comment: Off-topic, but you may want to clarify what you are trying to achieve more precisely, and what the context is. If you are in a scenario of "I manage a network and I see a device that is doing bad stuff/shouldn't be there and I need to find what/where it is" it may be related to security. But there are often more accurate ways to find information about the devices (if you manage them) or to avoid unwanted devices.

Answer (score 4):

A mac address doesn't identify a specific model of a device, but rather the  the likely manufacturer.  IEEE is the registration authority that contains a list of [manufacturer prefixes](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt).

This will ONLY tell you the *likely* vendor of the network device.  I say likely since MAC addresses can be changed programmatically to any value you want on most operating systems (I know Linux can).  This means I could be running a HP network card or usb network adapter, but alter my mac address to report HTC as the manufacturer.

Another issue is that the network device talking to the network may be a third party device such as a USB network adapter (ethernet or WiFi), and have nothing to do with the original laptop.

There are methods of fingerprinting a network device (NMap can do this), but those methods are *not* very reliable on anything except the most common of hardware.

Comment: Windows can change the MAC address too. Also, virtualbox allows you to set any MAC address you wish.

Comment: Also, in many cases it is the manufacturer of the Ethernet or Wi-Fi chip rather than the manufacturer of the whole computer (even if the chip is directly on the motherboard).